# How to introduce myself professionally in a workplace

Tags: professionalism

I will be working in a new company soon, I want to know how to introduce myself professionally.

I though of something like

> Hello, I am FirstName LastName, from Country, Working in CompanyName
>   Department DepartmentName

Maybe that is enough; I don't know. Do you have better suggestions?

Comment: Just first name is fine for introductions. If you're addressing a group then give more info.

Comment: There's a lot of variation from company culture too - "hey - I'm Dave from Systems" might be fine.  Your country of origin shouldn't matter at all, and it can be left as a conversation item for some other time.

Comment: What country is your new job in?

Comment: From his other questions, he's in the Netherlands. I think this will depend on company culture (which depends largely on company size and age).

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your culture and the nature of the company you're working in.

People will usually forget information on the first introduction, so we usually keep things simple.

Hi. I'm [First Name], I'm working with [Manager's Name] in [Department]

So, you're giving them your name and letting them know where you are in the company, leaving them only one thing to remember (your first name).  Any more information can come as part of natural conversation.  People may need to know your last name if they want to email you or add you into documentation, but this is something that people are used to asking.

Comment: I'd maybe had the main project you'll be working on if this could be relevant to the person you're talking to.

Answer (score 2):

Every company is different. You may even have differences within a company based on line of business, department, office location, etc. In these kinds of situations, I **just mirror what others do**.

Typically your name, general position title, and department are pretty standard.

When in doubt, my gotos are...

One-on-one introduction:

> *[hand outstretched for a handshake]* *FirstName* *LastName*. Nice to meet you.

Group introduction:

> *FirstName* *LastName*, I do *Role* in *Program/Department/Group*.

Generally, folks will have follow-on questions if they want to know more.